# TAHI compliance ( IPV6 ) in RHEL 5.5

Tags: linux, ipv6, rhel

We are planning for the ipv6 logo certification for our appliance box. We are running the TAHI suite (http://tahi.org/) for certifying the ipv6 compliance. I changed most of my sysctl settings in the RHEL 5.5 box to get it working.

I am having hard time to resolve the following:
1) Fragment Reassembly -- Fragment ID mismatch should give error
2) Fragment Reassembly -- Source Addresses Differ Between Fragments
3) Fragment Reassembly --  Destination Address Differ Between Fragments

My current configuration in sysctl pertaining to IPv6 is:

```
net.ipv6.conf.default.accept_dad=2
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_dad=2
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_dad=2
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.use_tempaddr=0
```

Can this be done via the ip6tables ? Any ideas on how this can be configured in RHEL 5.5 ?

Comment: SNORT is a viable solution in the case. It can detect and block the issues like IPV6 fragmentation.

Steps on using the snort on RHEL 5

http://linuxmantra.com/2010/10/install-snort-2-9-on-rhel-5.html

I am trying that out.... Will update this thread once done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## INSTALL PREREQUISITES

For the SNORT we need to install the following:

- flex byacc bison pcre-devel libdnet-devel zlib-devel
- We can download the above from:

ftp://ftp.univie.ac.at/systems/linux/dag/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/buildtools/RPMS/flex-2.5.35-0.8.el5.rfb.x86_64.rpm

ftp://fr2.rpmfind.net/linux/centos/5.10/os/x86_64/CentOS/byacc-1.9-29.2.2.x86_64.rpm

http://vault.centos.org/5.5/os/x86_64/CentOS/zlib-devel-1.2.3-3.x86_64.rpm

http://vault.centos.org/5.5/os/x86_64/CentOS/bison-2.3-2.1.x86_64.rpm

http://vault.centos.org/5.5/os/x86_64/CentOS/pcre-devel-6.6-2.el5_1.7.x86_64.rpm

ftp://ftp.univie.ac.at/systems/linux/dag/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/dag/RPMS/libdnet-1.11-1.2.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm

http://apt.sw.be/redhat/el5/en/x86_64/rpmforge/RPMS/libdnet-devel-1.11-1.2.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm

```
* Install the above said rpm in the below order:
rpm -ivh flex-2.5.35-0.8.el5.rfb.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh byacc-1.9-29.2.2.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh zlib-devel-1.2.3-3.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh bison-2.3-2.1.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh pcre-devel-6.6-2.el5_1.7.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh libdnet-1.11-1.2.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh libdnet-devel-1.11-1.2.el5.rf.x86_64.rpm
```

## DOWNLOAD THE REQUIRED SNORT & ALLIED LIBRARIES

http://www.tcpdump.org/release/libpcap-1.5.3.tar.gz
http://sourceforge.net/projects/snort.mirror/files/Snort%202.9.5.6/snort-2.9.5.6.tar.gz/download
http://sourceforge.net/projects/snort.mirror/files/Snort%202.9.5.6/daq-2.0.1.tar.gz/download

[ NOTE: The following assumes the above 3 are downloaded to the /opt/CSCOlumos/SNORT ]

## INSTALL LIBPCAP

cd /opt/CSCOlumos/SNORT

tar -xf libpcap-1.5.3.tar.gz

mv libpcap-1.5.3 /usr/local/src/

cd /usr/local/src/libpcap-1.5.3

./configure --prefix=/usr

make

make install

/sbin/ldconfig

## INSTALL DAQ AND SNORT

cd /opt/CSCOlumos/SNORT

tar -xf daq-2.0.1.tar.gz

cd daq-2.0.1

./configure

cd os-daq-modules

make

cd ..

make

make install

cd /opt/CSCOlumos/SNORT

tar -xf snort-2.9.5.6.tar.gz

cd snort-2.9.5.6

./configure

make

make install

## FIXING THE libdnet LIBRARY ISSUES

cp -rp /usr/lib/vmware-tools/lib32/libdnet.so.1 /usr/local/lib/

/sbin/ldconfig

updated

mkdir -p /var/log/snort/

touch /var/log/snort/alert

## TEST THE SNORT

snort --version

,,_     -*> Snort! <*-
  o"  )~   Version 2.9.5.6 GRE (Build 208)
   ''''    By Martin Roesch & The Snort Team: http://www.snort.org/snort/snort-team
           Copyright (C) 1998-2013 Sourcefire, Inc., et al.
           Using libpcap version 1.5.3
           Using PCRE version: 6.6 06-Feb-2006
           Using ZLIB version: 1.2.3

## CONFIGURING THE IPV6 FILTER AND RUNNING

vi /opt/test/SNORT/SNORT.conf

preprocessor frag3_global: max_frags 65536

preprocessor frag3_engine: policy linux 
                    bind_to 2001::99ed:d7c6:86f0:8e0a 
                    detect_anomalies

preprocessor frag3_engine: policy linux detect_anomalies

Now run as:

snort -c /opt/test/SNORT/SNORT.conf

NOTE: here the 2001::99ed:d7c6:86f0:8e0a is the eth0 (communication interface) ipv6 address.